# How to change Application Priority Programmatically in Golang for windows?

Tags: go

I have CPU intensive task and I want system and user programs have higher priority so my Golang application run only when the system is idle, or better using free CPU cores.

Like syscall.Setpriority(which int, who int, prio int) (err error)
But this just works on Linux not windows.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @oneofone : Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent for windows is [`SetPriorityClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx).